# Ambiguity with extension methods where both typed and untyped interface are implemented

Tags: c#, generics, ambiguity

Consider this code:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static bool isEmpty<T>(this ICollection<T> collection) {
        return collection.Count == 0;
    }

    public static bool isEmpty(this ICollection collection) {
        return collection.Count == 0;
    }
}

public class A {
    IList<string> typedList;
    IList rawList;
    List<string> list;

    public void b() {
        bool d = typedList.isEmpty();
        bool e = rawList.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Above code is no problem, for `IList` implements `ICollection`, and `IList<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`. Were we to remove one of the extension methods, one of the lines in `b()` wouldn't compile. That's why I declared both extension methods. However, a problem surfaces if we call `list.isEmpty()`: `ambiguous call`. That is, however, because `List<T>` implements **both** `ICollection` **and** `ICollection<T>`. How to circumnavigate this problem? Of course, I can add the extension method `isEmpty(this List<T> list)`, but that, naturally, doesn't fix any other collections which implement both a typed and an untyped interface (and that goes for any non-collections which implement a typed and an untyped version of the same interface as well).

Comment: The only way I can see is to tell compiler explicity which signature should use: `bool f = ((ICollection)list).isEmpty();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add Extension for `IEnumerable` which will work for all sequences.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsEmpty(this IEnumerable collection)
    {
        return !collection.Cast<object>().Any();
    }
}
```

Or

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsEmpty(this IEnumerable collection)
    {
        IEnumerator enumerator = null;
        try
        {
            enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();
            return !enumerator.MoveNext();
        }
        finally
        {
            IDisposable disposable = enumerator as IDisposable;
            if (disposable != null)
            {
                disposable.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldnt the GC dispose the enumerator?

Comment: @stealthjong Why would you think GC disposes enumerator? GC doesn't know what is `enumerator` or even `IDisposable`.  You ought to do that. That's your responsibility.

Comment: The C# compiler disposes the enumerator, part of the foreach() contract.  Stick with the first snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to determine the type and call the proper method but that would be an overkill. I would suggest creating an extension method that takes non-generic `IEnumerable` and implement it like this:

```
public static bool isEmpty(this IEnumerable collection) 
{
    var enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();
    if(enumerator.MoveNext()) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: The other anwser guy disposes the enumerator, but doesnt the GC do that? From .NET4.5 GC Fundamentals: "Reclaims objects that are no longer being used, clears their memory..."

Comment: @stealthjong The GC would collect objects that are no longer being used, performing a cycle to check them. At the end of cycle, it checks the references. If a variable is out of scope and/or there are no more references to it, its related piece of memory is cleared. The meaning of `Dispose` is to force this behavior, in order to "tell" the GC to explicitly clear the memory of an object, in order to avoid wasting memory that could used for other purposes, just because the GC doesn't perform continuously a check for unused objects.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano So that means it's not strictly necessary to call dispose on the enumerator?

Comment: @stealthjong It's not strictly necessary, but it's a good practice, since the IEnumerator<T> implements the IDisposable interface, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This means that you should dispose of it properly, as Sriram Sakthivel said, showing you the [Dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: The non-generic IEnumerator interface does not implement IDisposable, so you cannot dispose it.

Comment: @Dennis_E I don't think so. The List<T> has the GetEnumerator() method that returns an [Enumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x854yt9s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object, that implements IEnumerator and IDisposable interfaces.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano List<T> implements the generic IEnumerator<T> interface, which implements IDisposable. The non-generic IEnumerator does not.

Comment: To show how important to call `Dispose`: Try `File.ReadLines(..).IsEmpty()` without calling `Dispose`. It will leave the open file handle. Then try to write into same file, you'll get `IOException`. You ought to dispose it. HTS.

Comment: Absolutely. @Dennis_E Yes sorry, you are [right](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but since the user is using a List<T>, then it makes sense to implement the Dispose pattern.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano you were right, too. It is correctly implemented in this case (with a cast and a null check). If the enumerator happens to implement IDisposable, it will still be disposed correctly. So never mind me.

Comment: @Dennis_E Thanks. :-) What do you think about my previous comment, that was about the behavior of GC? Is there something else to consider or something to rephrase?

Comment: @AlbertoSolano It looks good to me. Disposing objects is good practice. Disposing saves the GC from having to do too much work. Not disposing can cause errors (like open file handles) and it can slow down your program.